# VSTS - Download triggering artifact

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I currently have a release defined for pushing clients to an internal nuget server.

Each release is identical in terms of steps, the only thing that changes is the triggering artifact.

However when I add another artifact to a "generic" release, so that there are now `ClientA` and `ClientB` artifacts on the release, both artifacts are downloaded when the release is triggered and they are both then pushed.

---

What I would like to know is if it is possible to have the release *only* download the triggering artifact.

Example:
A release is triggered on both `ClientA` and `ClientB`.

`ClientB` is released. The build triggers and only uses the `ClientB` artifact during the deployment.

Comment: Are they all build artifacts?

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT Yes, of two separate CI builds. `ClientA.CI` and `ClientB.CI`

Comment: there is `Download build artifacts ` release task from MS available but I can not make it works for several artifacts in the release https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is possible at the moment, but something similar is possible though.

Create a task group from the current release definition as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=vsts

There clone the release definition and change the artifact from ClientA to ClientB.

You'll end up having two release definition, both sharing the steps but the artifacts will be different.

**EDIT: PowerShell script to download Build artifacts**

Eddie suggested a nice workaround. Here's how you can pull down an artifact manually.

1. You need to enable [Allow scripts to access OAuth token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=vsts)
2. Add a PowerShell task to each phase and reference the [DownloadBuildArtifacts.ps1](https://gist.github.com/DanijelMalik/7e6a7826a884be00d92e90472bd4ea58#file-downloadbuildartifacts-ps1) script

If the release is triggered by build artifacts, the value of the pre-defined variable "$(RELEASE.TRIGGERINGARTIFACT.ALIAS)" will be the triggered artifacts alias. You can get the value of this variable to determine which artifact trigger the release.

Comment: Thanks Danijel but avoiding the multiple release definitions was what I was hoping for.

Comment: I updated the solution with a link to the PowerShell script. You'll probably have to tailor it to your needs, but it should give you a head start.

Comment: it would be useful to add `if ($artifact.Alias -eq $env:RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS) {` to accomplish initial question and to download the only one artifact that has triggered the release

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to achieve this out of box. But you can disable auto download artifacts and add a powershell script in your release definition to get the triggered artifact and download it.

Comment: Any direction on what that powershell script might look like / where I can find documentation on how to download the artifact and pass it to the next part of the build process?

Comment: Don't use a powershell task. Just use a [custom condition][https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml] to evaluate the value of `$(Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias)`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't the way to just download the triggered artifacts, but you can identify which artifact trigger this release through **RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS** variable.

So, you can push corresponding one per to that variable.

Comment: This might actually do the trick. I did notice a new icon on the triggering artifact recently so this might do the trick.