# AzureDevOps Release pipeline with multiple artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is it possible to have a single release pipeline with multiple artifacts that will trigger separate stages conditionally.

**Example:**

`(Build Artifact 1)` Build tags of `Web`

`(Build Artifact 2)` Build tags of `Identity`

When i setup my release pipeline I create one pipeline and add the

`(Build Artifact 1)` -> `Web Stage`

`(Build Artifact 2)` -> `Identity Stage`

both of those artifacts are set trigger a release automatically and set to `After Release`

The problem I have is that when I queue the build for `(Build Artifact 2)` both stages will deploy. And i only want `Identity Stage` to deploy and visa versa.

The reason i want everything in one pipeline is because then all my artifacts is contained in one pipeline, I know i can do this if i create separate pipelines.

Comment: it can be solved using powershell script to download artifacts that matches to $(RELEASE.TRIGGERINGARTIFACT.ALIAS) variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52030636/vsts-download-triggering-artifact

Answer (score 2):

Thinking more about your situation, it might be cleaner (read: no failing stages) to have a third artifact producing CI that is triggered on the build completion of the other 2 CI builds. That mediation build would get tagged according to why it was triggered (ie. `Web` or `Identity`). The artifact of this build would be a re-packaging of the upstream artifact (use the download artifact task), allowing your release pipeline to consume one artifact that might have 2 different tag values. This gives your artifact filters in pre-release conditions more teeth.

```
Web_CI                            
    \                             #Web - - Web Development - - Web Production
     - -\                        /
         > = WebIdSwitch_CI - - <
     - -/                        \
    /                             #Id - - Id Development - - Id Production
Id_CI
```

---

*Original Answer*

I could be wrong about this, but I think you're going to need to have the stages run based on the value in `RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS`.

There might be a couple ways to do this, such as

1. having a buffer stage for per artifact after release and letting them fail if the value isn't right (moving your working stage to execute after its buffer)
2. do the check in the job with a new first task and fail that
3. write a conditional execution option on every task to make sure that none of them execute if the triggering artifact isn't right

The variable can be accessed on the pipeline using `$(Release.TriggeringArtifact.Alias)` or in powershell with `$env:RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS`.

I'm not sure if you're using Artifact Filters on your stages already as part of your pre-deployment conditions, but that may be another way that isn't as much of a hack. I'll have to put a test pipeline together and try it out.

Comment: The RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT seems like a good way to go about it. Currently i am using artifact filters based of the build tags. Will have to try and see if there is a way to trigger the release based of the TRIGGERINGARTIFACT

Comment: yea i cant get this right, do you have an example of how i can achieve this by using the RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS

Comment: I'll make an edit to my answer with an example, and I'll goof with my test org to get on a clean solution.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you can get at the variable using the $(Release.Triggeringartifact.Alias) variable in your pipeline, or using the $env:RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS syntax for powershell.