# Is it possible to use $(RELEASE.TRIGGERINGARTIFACT.ALIAS) as a condition to trigger different release stages?

Tags: azure-devops

My problem is almost same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55734824/azuredevops-release-pipeline-with-multiple-artifacts). However, I don't really get the comments or the solutions proposed there.

Say I have two artifacts: A1 and A2.

```
A1---> Dev stage
A2---> UAT stage.
```

What I want is that when A1 is released, only Dev stage is deployed. But at the moment, when A1 is rleased, Dev and UAT are triggered.

looking at the comments from previous question,

1. how can $(RELEASE.TRIGGERINGARTIFACT.ALIAS) be used as a trigger condition? Looking at filter, I can't see a place to put custom condition
2. If I create a third artifact as suggested, how can I set different tag base on if A1 or A2 is built?
3. If there other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Say I have two artifacts: A1 and A2.

Open `Dev stage` ->click Agent job->expand Additional options and select Custom condition using variable expressions-> add the condition `eq(variables['RELEASE.TRIGGERINGARTIFACT.ALIAS'], 'A1')`. The Dev stage only runs when the value of RELEASE.TRIGGERINGARTIFACT.ALIAS is A1, otherwise this stage will be skipped.

The same configuration in `UAT stage`, the condition is `eq(variables['RELEASE.TRIGGERINGARTIFACT.ALIAS'], 'A2')`

[image]

In my release pipeline, I update the Artifact `_test` to trigger this release pipeline and the variable `RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS` is `_test`, it runs `Stage 1` and skip `Stage 2`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the exact answer, but it still can work as a solution to your problem.

You can `tag` your builds depending on the produced artifact name. If the build produces artifact `A1`, add a tag `A1` to it. That way you can set up release stage conditions based on `artifact filters` like this:

[image]

For the `Dev` stage trigger, filter build tags by `A1` and for the `UAT` trigger, filter by `A2`.

Comment: but this will trigger both I think

Comment: actually, I cecided to merge two build pipeline into one and then uses branch filter in release. This makes things much easier.